# Check Color in DatagridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a Datagrid which i fill programmatically. I need to Check the Color from a Cell, but always get "{Name=0, ARGB=(0, 0, 0, 0)}".
My Code to check the Color:

```
Dim backColor As Color = DataGridViewMoney.Item(DataGridViewMoney.Rows.Count - 1, 0).Style.BackColor
```

How to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Item(DataGridViewMoney.Rows.Count - 1, 0)` 

to `Item(0,DataGridViewMoney.Rows.Count - 1)` if you want get first column (cell).

Try this code:

```
Dim backColor As Color = DataGridViewMoney.Item(0, DataGridViewMoney.Rows.Count - 1).InheritedStyle.BackColor
```

Then you can get:

`backColor.ToKnownColor.ToString` - name of the color (if known) or zero

`backColor.IsKnownColor` - boolean value if colors is known

`backColor.Name` - name or hexadecimal value

`backColor.ToString` - "Color [name]" or ARGB values

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your code: [DataGridView.Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158656%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property parameters are `columnIndex` and `rowIndex`, in this order.

Please also note that `Empty` color (`{Name=0, ARGB=(0, 0, 0, 0)}`) is the standard color of a `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` so this result could be correct.

You can use this code to verify if it works:

```
'set a backcolor different from Empty
DataGridViewMoney.Item(0, DataGridViewMoney.Rows.Count - 1).Style.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine

'check backcolor
MsgBox(DataGridViewMoney.Item(0, DataGridViewMoney.Rows.Count - 1).Style.BackColor.ToString)
```